# Mapping sub-domain in Digital Ocean

Tags: dns, domain

I am trying to map `ugc.domain.com` to `domain.com/ugc` on my website which is hosted on Digital Ocean.

What I've tried:

1. Clicked `CNAME` in the Digital Ocean Domains panel
2. Name: `ugc`
3. Hostname: `domain.com/ugc.`

Result:

[image]

Am I misunderstanding how mapping these sub-domains work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `CNAME` from `ugc.domain.com` to `domain.com`.

Then, on your Apache or Nginx configuration, be sure to create a virtual host/server block whose name is `ugc.domain.com` and redirects to `domain.com/ugc`.

Comment: Oh, woops. So this is a server config and has nothing to do with DNS settings?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage The DNS entry will link the IP of the subdomain to your domain (the browser will still think it's going to `ugc.domain.com` but it just has the same IP as `domain.com`), and the server config entry will actually perform the redirect ("oh look, this user wants `/` of `ugc.domain.com`. Let's redirect them to `domain.com/ugc`).

Comment: I gotcha. I actually have the IP correctly linked to my domain. I guess I was just confused on what I needed to do if I want to map `ugc.domain.com` to `domain.com/ugc`. Do you mind telling me what I need to do within my Virtual Host to map that?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage See http://serverfault.com/a/120507/201357